# Trying to reuse ImageView in Android

Tags: android, layout, view, imageview, reusability

I am attempting to reuse `ImageView` objects in a `RelativeLayout` to avoid the cost of memory allocation. Specifically I create an `ImageView` programatically, and associate a fade animatiom with it. The animation runs and in `onAnimationEnd()` I set visibility to `GONE` and push the `ImageView` on a queue. When I next want to repeat this process I look to see if there is an `ImageView` on the queue and if so use this instead of requesting a new one. There is quite a delay between these uses so the animation is definitely done and dusted. The problem is that whilst the reused view will accept new `ImageResource`, I cannot get it to accept new `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` to set the view to a different position in the layout! Any help much appreciated

Comment: how are you applying the new layoutparams. are you removing the view and adding it again.

Comment: I have tried to remove the View and add again. I have also tried the following parentView.updateViewLayout(view, lp). Exactly the same effect The view draws with its new image but in the place on screen it was originally set to.